# wrap() doesn't work well with after()

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(".modal-body").after($('.myDiv').wrap('<form></form>'));
```

the after method of .myDiv did work but it did not wrapped within ? I also tried like this

```
$('.myDiv').wrap('<form></form>');
$(".modal-body").after($('.myDiv'));
```

but doesn't worked.

My desired result is my .myDiv wrapped with form tag and been placed after modal.

Comment: Do you mean insertAfter, instead of after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wrapping the `.myDiv` element with a `form` but the `wrap` element will return the element set which called it that is the `myDiv` element, so the `after()` call will receive the `myDiv` element as its param, so it will move the `myDiv` element only not the wrapped `form`

```
$(".modal-body").after($('.myDiv').wrap('<form></form>').parent());
```

Demo: [Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kfk532o1/2/) - [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kfk532o1/)

Comment: after vs insert after differences is?

Comment: @JamesLemon using after... `$(".modal-body").after($form);`... http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kfk532o1/4/